# IN ARIZONA is there a time limit for a police officer to file a complaint or ticket they have written you

Tags: criminal-law, arizona, statute-of-limitations

If I Have been written a criminal ticket for -Indecent Exposure-, and my stated court appearance date came and the clerk of the court said that i wasn't on the docket because they hadn't even turned their copy of the ticket in yet ........ In arizona, how long do i have before they cannot turn their copy of the ticket in?  is there a filing time limit ?

Comment: Purely hypothetically, of course

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the statute of limitations in your jurisdiction. Because it is not yet filed, there are no charges against you, so nothing in the realm of "speedy trial" lends itself to your cause here. A lot of states have a two year statute of limitations for misdemeanors, so it may be two years that the officer has to submit your ticket.